# Error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]

Tags: c++, gcc, build, gcc-warning, mitk

I am trying to compile mitk on ubuntu and I got this error :

> error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]

Here there is a part of code :

```
      /** Get memory offset for a given image index */
      unsigned int GetOffset(const IndexType & idx) const
      {
       const unsigned int * imageDims = m_ImageDataItem->m_Dimensions;

        unsigned int offset = 0;
        switch(VDimension)
        {
        case 4:
         offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
        case 3:
        offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
        case 2:
        offset  = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
         break;
        }

        return offset;
      }
```

I would be appreciate for any help please.

Comment: That fallthrough looks deliberate to me.

Comment: Reopened. This does not look like a duplicate of the other question; the fall-through here looks deliberate, and the problem is the overly-aggressive compiler settings that turn fall-through into an error.

Comment: If deliberate, add `[[fallthrough]]`.

Comment: It looks like you're compiling with some setting that turns every warning into an error. If you do that you have to live with the consequences: the compiler thinks you're not smart enough to have intended to do what you did, so it refuses to compile your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't think it is deliberate at all.  I think it is a misunderstanding that case 4 wont fall through to case 3 since 4 comes after 3, numerically.

Comment: @PeteBecker your comment can be read as compiling with warnings as errors would be something bad. Unfortunately sometimes warning have false positives and in such case you only want to silence the compiler, not fix anything on the code

Comment: @user463035818 -- you got my message. <g> Seriously: I know that some people like this setting. It's a royal pain when you're trying to write portable code, and have to dodge every compiler's peculiarities. An infinite loop with a conditional return statement can produce a warning that the code is missing a return statement (after the loop); adding a return statement produces a warning from a different compiler about unreachable code.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- this looks like a cumulative calculation where the high-order parts are only used for high-dimensional objects.

Comment: can you please clarify in the question if the fallthrough is intentional? ie for case 2, `offset` should be the sum of all terms? In your question it is actually not 100% clear if the warning is a false positive or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add keyword break to each case statement, if you don't do that, the code will run from case which it matches condition and continue to meet the

> break;

for example: If VDimension = 4, then the code will run from case 4 => continue to case 3 => contine to case 2 then break. It means that it will execute below commands:

```
offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
offset  = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
break;
return offset;
```

I think your code should be:

```
/** Get memory offset for a given image index */
  unsigned int GetOffset(const IndexType & idx) const
  {
   const unsigned int * imageDims = m_ImageDataItem->m_Dimensions;

    unsigned int offset = 0;
    switch(VDimension)
    {
    case 4:
     offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
     break;
    case 3:
     offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
     break;
    case 2:
     offset  = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
     break;
    }

    return offset;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that would get rid of the warning. But it would probably break the code, which looks like it intentionally relies on fallthrough.

Comment: I don't think that is the case, but if it is, we need to remove some flag when compiling

Answer (score 18):

Switch case statements will fall through by default. In the case of the shown program, if `VDimension` is 4 then all of

```
offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
offset  = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
```

will be executed.

In some other languages, such as Pascal, only one case is executed and there is no concept of fall through. As such, programmers new to C++ may write fall through switches unintentionally.

If the fall through is unintentional, you need to add a break between each case to not fall through.

> this statement may fall through

This warning notifies the programmer about the fall through. This warning option can be controlled with the GCC compiler switch `-Wimplicit-fallthrough`. It is not enabled by default and is not enabled by `-Wall`, but it is enabled by `-Wextra`.

Warnings become errors if the `-Werror` switch is used. `-Werror` is not enabled by default.

C++17 introduced `[[fallthrough]]` attribute, which can be used to explicitly document the fall through when it is intentional. The compiler should not warn if it is used:

```
        switch(VDimension)
        {
        case 4:
         offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
         [[fallthrough]];
        case 3:
         offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
         [[fallthrough]];
        case 2:
         offset = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
         break;
        }
```

Prior to C++17, GCC provides a language extension attribute `__attribute__ ((fallthrough))` for the same purpose.

The fall through can also be documented with a comment, and `Wimplicit-fallthrough` may detect such comment depending on what value was used with the switch. More details in the documentation of GCC.

Comment: A link to the fallthrough attribute, or an example using it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you're absolutely sure the warnings are inconsequential, remove the `-Werror` flag during compilation.

For projects which put the flag during configure stage, you can do

`./configure --disable-werror`

before running

`make`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code is correct, just add `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` to the compiler flags if you can.  This is often `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` in the Makefile.

As others have said, the code for cases 4, 3, and 2 will be executed in that order when VDimension is 4 because there are no `break` statements to stop it.  If that's the intended behavior (and I suspect it is) then the compiler is annoyingly warning you that the switch statement is doing exactly what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
      /** Get memory offset for a given image index */
  unsigned int GetOffset(const IndexType & idx) const
  {
   const unsigned int * imageDims = m_ImageDataItem->m_Dimensions;

    unsigned int offset = 0;
    switch(VDimension)
    {
    case 4:
     offset = offset + idx[3]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1]*imageDims[2];
     break;
    case 3:
    offset = offset + idx[2]*imageDims[0]*imageDims[1];
     break;
    case 2:
    offset  = offset + idx[0] + idx[1]*imageDims[0];
     break;
    }

    return offset;
  }
```

Just add "break;" after finish any case.